# i have to check if a string is palindrom or not using string iterate

Tags: c++

Why am I getting an error in the following code?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{  string str;
    string temp;
   string :: reverse_iterator it;
   cout<<"enter the word"<<endl;
   getline(cin,str);
   temp=str;
   cout<<temp;

     for(it=str.rbegin();it != str.rend(); it++)

     {
         cout<<*it;


     }
      if(temp.compare(*it)==0)

      cout<<"palindrome";
      else cout<<"not a palindrome";


     return 0;

}
```

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:29:23: error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
       if(temp.compare(*it)==0)
                       ^~~~
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what's in that picture? Unfortunately I am blind, and my screen reader only spells out gibberish for that line.

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific question. (or for that matter, *any* question).

Comment: `std::string::compare()` takes a `std::string` or a null-terminated `const char*` string as input, but you are passing it a single `char` from `*it` instead. That is what the compiler error is complaining about. And even if you fix that, your code would still fail, since `it` would be `str.rend()` when `compare()` is called, and it is not valid to dereference the `rend()` iterator.

Answer (score 1):

It will not solve your entire problem, but notice the syntax:

```
string :: reverse_iterator it;
```

is ill-formed and produces compilation error.

---

You can conveniently do like this (notice the comments for explanation):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

// Applying this statement in order to make ONLY this
// program simpler.
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  string input;
  bool exp = false;

  cout << "Enter a word: ";
  cin >> input;

  // Defining a reverse iterator and a simple iterator
  string::reverse_iterator rit = input.rbegin();
  string::iterator it = input.begin();

  // Comparing both iterators simultaneously
  for(; rit != input.rend() && it != input.end(); rit++, it++) {
    exp = exp && (*rit == *it);
    if (!exp) break;
  }

  // Using a ternary operation to save the number of lines
  cout << "The string is " << (exp ? "palindrome" : "not palindrome") << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

---

**Some test cases:**

```
Enter a word: hello
The string is not palindrome

Enter a word: radar
The string is palindrome
```

Comment: "*Expression is true if both pointers on the iteration are equal*" - you are not comparing *pointers*, you are comparing *characters*. Your loop does not detect a palindrome correctly, when the loop is finished the value of `exp` is just the result of the *last* pair of characters that were compared, which is the 1st and Last string characters since you loop through the whole string. Your example says "hello" is not a palindrome (h <> o) and "radar" is (r == r). A simple fix would be to initialize `exp=true`, have the loop use `exp = exp && (*rit == *it);` and break the loop when `exp==false`

Comment: You should break out of the loop as soon as you found that the string is not a palindrome. You will false-positive if the first char is equal to last. Also, you don't need to go passed the middle of the string

Comment: @RemyLebeau fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to not use a reverse iterator. The string is a palindrome if its last character equals its first character, its next-to-last character equals its second character, and so on, stopping at the **middle** of the string. Yes, you can go all the way through the string, but when you reach the middle you know the answer. So:

```
template <class Iter>
bool is_palindrome(Iter first, Iter last) {
    while (last > first) {
        --last;
        if (*first != *last)
            return false;
        ++first;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Yes, this requires random access iterators. Fortunately, `std::string`'s iterators are random access.